# Google Analytics UA to GA4 migration

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, dashboard, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

Earlier I was using Universal analytics(UA) version to track my Chatbot(both Teams and webapp) mainly feedbacks and suggestions from users. But from 1st July 2023, the UA version is discontinued, hence I have to migrate my UA to GA4.
[GA4 dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ktEE.png)
I have completed the set up required for migrating UA to GA4 after following all the suggested steps of google analytics documentation (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13486733?hl=en),  still I'm facing following issues in GA4-

1. My website's data is not getting reflected in the GA4.
2. The number of users shown in the dashboard is still zero.
3. I am not able to generate dashboards, reports in GA4.
4. I want to track my chatbot based website and create reports,
   Since so long days, I'm struggling to fix above issues, it will be great if someone can help me to fix this.

I'm facing following issues in GA4-

1. My website's data is not getting reflected in the GA4.
2. The number of users shown in the dashboard is still zero.
3. I am not able to generate dashboards, reports in GA4.
4. I want to track my chatbot based website and create reports,
   Since so long days, I'm struggling to fix above issues, it will be great if someone can help me to fix this.